# I want to msg a phone using sms but have it send the person back after the text is complete like "telprompt" but for sms

Tags: ios, sms

I am wondering if there is a way "sms" can take a person back to the app when they are done with their text? I know the phone method can by using "telprompt:%@" but can the sms be done that way as well so something like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: @"smsprompt:%@"];
```

or is there a different method to do this as the example above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no URL scheme like `telprompt:` for SMS, you should even not use `telprompt:` since it is not an official URL scheme and might be removed by Apple is some future version of iOS with warning.

You can use the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to present the SMS composer in you own app.